# Schedule a Webservice call using spring integration

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-integration

I want to schedule (with date time) a Webservice call using Spring integration. I am planning to use the below configuration to invoke the REST Webservice. I am new to Webservice and SI. Could any of you help me to come up with a scheduler to do the same?

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="sampleRequestChannel"
    reply-channel="sampleReplyChannel"
    url="http://<server details>"
    http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" />
```

Comment: Does you program do more that this? If no, why not using the system scheduler? Otherwise you can either get in Quartz scheduler and trigger a run through a MessageGateway or use Spring Batch if you want to extend this further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I need to schedule this WS call based on the date and time provided by the user which they will be modifying frequently. :(  I will be getting those date time details from database based on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the data from DB there is JDBC adapters. One of them is:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:poller/>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

with which you can `poll` some table in DB periodically for the fresh value of date and time and send it as a `payload` to the Spring Integration flow.

Another is `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` which is based on the upstream flow and can be triggered by user event.